# How to design a template class with switchable member variables at compile-time in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++

**| ■ Probelm definition____________________**

I'm trying to design a **super-flexible, but memory efficient** module satisfying below properties.

> 1. It can **switch OFF unnecessary member variables** depending on the situation.
> 2. Which variables it will own are determined **at the compile-time**.

I somehow made one which determines its member list **"*before*" the compile-time**, using **macros** and **enumerator flags**. see below :

**▼ TraitSwitch.h**

```
#pragma once
// Macros to switch-off source codes themselves.
#define ON                 1
#define OFF                0

#define TRI_AREA_INFO      ON
#define TRI_CENTROID_INFO  ON
#define TRI_NORMAL_INFO    OFF // When the normal vector info is unnecessary.
...
```

**▼ TriangleTraits.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include "TraitSwitch.h"

enum TriangleTrait : uint8_t
{
    NONE          = 0,   // 0000 0000

#if (TRI_AREA_INFO == ON)
    AREA          = 1,   // 0000 0001
#endif

#if (TRI_CENTROID_INFO == ON)
    CENTROID      = 2,   // 0000 0010
#endif

#if (TRI_NORMAL_INFO == ON) //        | Inactive Preprocessor Block
    NORMAL_VECTOR = 4,   // 0000 0100 |
#endif
    ... // more traits

    ALL           = 255  // 1111 1111
}
// Need some additional overloaded bitwise-operators (&, |, |=, etc ...)
```

**▼ Triangle.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "TriangleTraits.h"

class Triangle
{
public:
    Triangle() {}
    ~Triangle() {}

#if (TRI_AREA_INFO == ON)
    double area;
#endif

#if (TRI_CENTROID_INFO == ON)
    double centroid[3]; // x, y, z
#endif

#if (TRI_NORMAL_INFO == ON) //   | Inactive Preprocessor Block
    double normal[3]; // x, y, z |
#endif
    ...

    TriangleTrait alreadyComputed; // To avoid redundant works.
    void ComputeTraits(TriangleTrait _requested)
    {
        if (((_requested & TriangleTrait::AREA) != 0) 
            && ((alreadyComputed & _requested) == 0))
        {
            this->ComputeArea();
            alreadyComputed |= TriangleTrait::AREA;
        }
        ... // do the same things for centroid, normal
    }

private:
    void ComputeArea();
    void ComputeCentroid();
    void ComputeNormal();
    ...
}
```

then, **C++ IntelliSense** on the object may show : [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sog4W.png)

**▼ main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Triangle.h"

int main(void)
{
    Triangle tri;
    tri.ComputeTraits(TriangleTrait::AREA | TriangleTrait::CENTROID);

    std::cout << "area : " << tri.area << "m²" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "centroid : (" 
        << tri.centroid[0] << "," 
        << tri.centroid[1] << "," 
        << tri.centroid[2] << ")" << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

Firstly ***Triangle.h*** looks quite ugly, and even if it looks good, this method determines class members **"*before"* the compile-time**, anyway.

**| ■ Question summary____________________**

*"How to design a template class with **switchable members**, which are determined **at the compile-time**."*

Here's the very thing what I want :

**▼ main.cpp**

```
...

int main(void)
{
    Triangle<__MACRO_DEFINED_TRAIT_SWITCH(AREA)> tri1; // This owns area info only
    tri1.area;

    Triangle<__MACRO_DEFINED_TRAIT_SWITCH(AREA | CENTROID)> tri2; // This owns area & centroid info
    tri2.area;
    tri2.centroid;

    Triangle<__MACRO_DEFINED_TRAIT_SWITCH(AREA | NORMAL)> tri3; // This owns area & normal vector info
    tri3.area;
    tri3.normal;
    ...

    Triangle<__MACRO_DEFINED_TRAIT_SWITCH(AREA | CENTROID | NORMAL)> tri4; // This owns area & centroid & normal vector info
    tri4.area;
    tri4.centroid;
    tri4.normal;
    ...
}
```

I guess using **templates combined with macros** (with *Tag-dispatching* method, maybe?) will do exactly what I want, but have no any clear idea.

Comment: 'Which are determined at the run-time'. As template classes are determined at compile time, you will never be able to determine it at runtime (same for the macros obviously). This seems a dead end.

Comment: @Jean Oh I confused 3: *Before compile-time* & *At compile-time* & *At run-time*. I'll edit my question right away. Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake! :D

Comment: Sounds like you want `std::tuple`.

Comment: @L.F. | Yeap, of course `std::tuple` is simple, good. But I think calling every trait like `double& area = std::get<0>(tri)` does not provide very good readability of code. Plus, the sequence of parameters becomes too critical for it.:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of distress, I found a way. So I'll answer my question myself.

The soultion was tooooo simple. Just use **multiple inheritances with variadic templates**. See below:

**▼TriangleTraits.h**

```
struct AREA
{
    double area;
};

struct CENTROID
{
    double centroid[3];
};

struct NORMAL
{
    double normal[3];
};
... // more traits

// Multiple Inheritances with variadic template
template<class... Traits>
struct TriangleWithTraits : Traits... 
{
};
```

**▼main.cpp**

```
#include "TriangleTraits.h" // Just include this one is enough

int main()
{
    TriangleWithTraits<AREA> tri1;
    tri1.area;

    TriangleWithTraits<AREA, CENTROID> tri2;
    tri2.area;
    tri2.centroid;

    TriangleWithTraits<AREA, NORMAL> tri3;
    tri3.area;
    tri3.normal;

    TriangleWithTraits<AREA, CENTROID, NORMAL> tri4;
    tri4.area;
    tri4.normal;
    tri4.centroid;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot use preprocessor to parse template parameter, preprocesssor does not know of C++.

But there's `std::conditional` and there's Empty Base optimization.

So you can have bases with data class parts, and `std::conditional` to select between them and empty base:

```
struct EmptyBase {};

struct BaseWithChar
{
    char a;
};

struct BaseWithLongLong
{
    long long b;
    long long c;
};

template<int Flags>
struct A
    : std::conditional<(Flags & 1), BaseWithChar, EmptyBase>::type
    , std::conditional<(Flags & 2), BaseWithLongLong, EmptyBase>::type
{
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(A<1>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(A<2>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(A<3>) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And with later C++ standards, there's `std::coditional_t` and `[[no_unique_address]]`:

```
using namespace std;

struct EmptyMember {};

template<int Flags>
struct A
{
    [[no_unique_address]] typename std::conditional_t<(Flags & 1), char, EmptyMember> a;
    [[no_unique_address]] typename std::conditional_t<(Flags & 2), long long, EmptyMember> b;
    [[no_unique_address]] typename std::conditional_t<(Flags & 2), long long, EmptyMember> c;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(A<1>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(A<2>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(A<3>) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But `[[no_unique_address]]` requires C++20, and without `[[no_unique_address]]` empty member will use some space. Looks like it does not work with Visual C++, even with 2019 preview. I've posted [feebdack](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/954963/no-unique-address-attribute-isnt-working.html).

With earlier C++, when you don't have `std::conditional` or `boost::conditional`, you can easily implement your own, it is just a template with true and false specialization. See "possible implementation" on [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! :D I was not familiar with `std::conditional`, so I had to study it for myself a little. I found *EmptyMember* only takes 1 byte of memory, so it can be said good for memory efficiency. But this method is a little bit far from what I wanted, since the class still have to possess all traits in it, even though they do not take much memory. So whenever you press **Ctrl+SpaceBar** on the object, every member will appear on the suggestion window. I found some way to solve my problem by myself, using **multiple inheritances with variadic template**. Thank you once again