# (C++11) Is there any way to limit scope of template parameters on a specific class?

Tags: c++, c++11

**■ Problem Definition_________________________**

**`!!`**`You can skip here and directly go to`**`■ Question Summary !!`**

I designed a **flexible but memory-efficient** class that suits various situations, having only **selective traits** within it : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733043/how-to-design-a-template-class-with-switchable-member-variables-at-compile-time/60768206#60768206)

Plus, I gave **ID** for each trait, which is used when a user wants to **request only specific traits** of the class.

I wrote my own class satisfying these properties, using **multiple inheritances** of **unnamed enums** with **variadic template**.

See below :

**▼ TriTraits.h**

```
struct TriT
{
    struct Centroid
    {
        Point3D centroid;
        struct ID { enum : utin8_t { CENTROID = 1 }; }; // 0000 0001
    };

    struct Area
    {
        double area;
        struct ID { enum : utin8_t { AREA = 2 }; }; // 0000 0010
    };

    struct Perimeter
    {
        double perimeter;
        struct ID { enum : utin8_t { PERIMETER = 4 }; }; // 0000 0100
    };
    ... // More traits...
};
```

**▼ Triangle.h**

```
#include "TriTraits.h"

enum class TRI_TRAIT_ID : uint8_t {}; // strong type
template<class... Traits>
struct TriangleT : Traits...
{
    struct IDs : Traits::ID...
    {
        enum : uint8_t {
            NONE = 0, // 0000 0000
            ALL = 255 // 1111 1111
        };
    };
    void ComputeTrait(TRI_TRAIT_ID _requestedIDs)
    {
        ... // Implementation will be written somehow, using bitwise & operator.
    }
};
```

For example, if one defines one's own triangle type, `MyTri<TriT::Area, TriT::Perimeter> myTri`, what compiler sees may look like this :

```
struct MyTri
{
    double area;
    double perimeter;

    struct IDs // Since enum can't be inherited, it has 3 individual unnamed enums in it
    {
        enum : uint8_t { AREA = 2 };
        enum : uint8_t { PERIMETER = 4 };
        enum : uint8_t {
            NONE = 0,
            ALL = 255
        };
    };
} myTri;
```

This custom triangle type will compute **some of** its traits by calling `ComputeTraits(...)` with bitwise `|operator`, like this :

```
myTri.ComputeTraits(MyTri::IDs::AREA | MyTri::IDs::PERIMETER); // Compute area and perimeter
```

**The problem rises here** : suppose there are **`Rectangle.h`** and **`Pentagon.h`, ... `NthPolygon.h`**, in the same manner.

I want each of my **custom polygon types** to get a **strongly-typed** parameter for its `ComputeTrait(...)`(So I used enum class for it), to prevent silly operations taking **mixed types of polygon traits**, such as

```
myTri.ComputeTraits(MyTri::IDs::AREA | MyRect::IDs::PERIMETER); // Mixed traits of a triangle and of  a rectangle.
```

So I want to overload `|operator` which takes only **unnamed enum**s in each scope of `NthPolygon::IDs::...`.

I tried writing the overloaded template operator **inside** the `private` scope of `NthPolygon::IDs::...`, but this failed since in-class operator overloading always takes the first parameter as itself : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709048/c-overloading-operator-for-struct-error-too-many-parameters)

Making it `friend` of global scope also failed, since there will be more than 1 overloaded `|operator`s for every N-th Polygon classes.

```
enum class N_TH_POLYGON_TRAIT_ID : uint8_t {}; // strong type
struct NthPolygon
{
    ...
    struct IDs
    {
        ...
     private:
        template<typename TRAIT_ID1, typename TRAIT_ID2>
        N_TH_POLYGON_TRAIT_ID operator|(TRAIT_ID1 _id1, TRAIT_ID2 _id2) // Error : too many operators for this operator function
        { return static_cast<N_TH_POLYGON_TRAIT_ID>(static_cast<utin8_t>(_id1) | static_cast<utin8_t>(_id2)); }

        template<typename TRAIT_ID1, typename TRAIT_ID2>
        friend N_TH_POLYGON_TRAIT_ID operator|(TRAIT_ID1 _id1, TRAIT_ID2 _id2) // Error : more than 1 operator "|" matches these operands
        { return static_cast<N_TH_POLYGON_TRAIT_ID>(static_cast<utin8_t>(_id1) | static_cast<utin8_t>(_id2)); }
    };
} myTri;
```

**■ Question Summary_________________________**

In the situation below, how can one make the template overloaded `operator|` take only parameters(unnamed enums) from the specific class?

```
enum class STRONG_TYPE_TRI_TRAIT_ID : uint8_t {};
struct Triangle
{
    struct IDs {
        enum : utin8_t { A = 1 };
        enum : utin8_t { B = 2 };
        enum : utin8_t { C = 3 };
    };
};
template<typename TRI_TRAIT_ID1, typename TRI_TRAIT_ID2>
STRONG_TYPE_TRI_TRAIT_ID operator|(TRI_TRAIT_ID1 _id1, TRI_TRAIT_ID2 _id2)
{ return static_cast<STRONG_TYPE_TRI_TRAIT_ID>(static_cast<uint8_t>(_id1) | static_cast<uint8_t>(_id2)); }
```

```
enum class STRONG_TYPE_RECT_TRAIT_ID : uint8_t {};
struct Rectangle
{
    struct IDs {
        enum : utin8_t { A = 1 };
        enum : utin8_t { B = 2 };
        enum : utin8_t { C = 3 };
    };
};
template<typename RECT_TRAIT_ID1, typename RECT_TRAIT_ID2>
STRONG_TYPE_RECT_TRAIT_ID operator|(RECT_TRAIT_ID1 _id1, RECT_TRAIT_ID2 _id2)
{ return static_cast<STRONG_TYPE_RECT_TRAIT_ID >(static_cast<uint8_t>(_id1) | static_cast<uint8_t>(_id2)); }
```

```
int main(void)
{
    Triangle::IDs::A | Triangle::IDs::B;  // OK
    Triangle::IDs::A | Rectangle::IDs::B; // Error
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it fill your requirement, but you might do something like:

```
template <typename Tag>
struct TriT
{
    enum class ID_t : uint8_t {};
    friend ID_t operator | (ID_t lhs, ID_t rhs)
    {
        return ID_t(uint8_t(lhs) | uint8_t(rhs));
    }

    struct Centroid
    {
        Point3D centroid;
        struct ID { static const ID_t CENTROID = ID_t(1); }; // 0000 0001
    };

    struct Area
    {
        double area;
        struct ID { static const ID_t AREA = ID_t(2); }; // 0000 0010
    };

    struct Perimeter
    {
        double perimeter;
        struct ID { static const ID_t PERIMETER = ID_t(4); }; // 0000 0100
    };

};

template<typename TRI_TRAIT_ID, class... Traits>
struct TriangleT : Traits...
{
    struct IDs : Traits::ID...
    {
        static constexpr TRI_TRAIT_ID NONE = TRI_TRAIT_ID(0);
        static constexpr TRI_TRAIT_ID ALL = TRI_TRAIT_ID(255);
    };
    void ComputeTrait(TRI_TRAIT_ID _requestedIDs)
    {
        // Implementation will be written somehow, using bitwise & operator.
    }
};
```

With usage:

```
struct TriTag;
struct RectTag;

using MyTri = TriangleT<TriT<TriTag>::ID_t, TriT<TriTag>::Area, TriT<TriTag>::Perimeter>;
using MyRect = RectT<TriT<RectTag>::ID_t, TriT<RectTag>::Area, TriT<RectTag>::Perimeter>;

int main()
{
    MyTri myTri;

    myTri.ComputeTrait(MyTri::IDs::AREA | MyTri::IDs::PERIMETER);
    //myTri.ComputeTrait(MyTri::IDs::AREA | MyRect::IDs::PERIMETER); // error as expected
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa9cf59154c9a773)

Comment: Without doubt, it works! I forgot there is **static** strong-type int doing as good as ENUMs. To add a little improvement to your answer, you may not have to put `ID_t` inside of the template class, which always carries `<type>` stuff. (And even no need of **template** overloaded `|operator`, too)

Comment: This is good, though, I am still curious about is there any way to confine template parameters in a specific range, in a grammatical approach like this : `template<typename UpperLevel::LowerClass> void Func(LowerClass _params) {...};`

Comment: I'm not sure if `TriT` are traits only for triangle or not, and if different triangle type can shared traits. The Tag template solve the more constraint. You can adapt solution to your needs.